# How to create a toggle button using jQuery

Tags: jquery, button

I am trying to toggle a button using below code.

```
import $ from "jquery";

$(".clickMe").click(function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    return text === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
  })
});

const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<button class="clickMe">ON </button>'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple problem in your code.

1. Dynamic created markup need delegated event handlers.
2. You have extra space on button text. You need to `trim()` text to avoid extra space before proceed.

Example:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.clickMe', function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    var txt = text.trim();
    return txt === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
  })
});
const rootApp = document.getElementById("root");
rootApp.innerHTML = '<button class="clickMe">ON </button>'
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Or only jQuery Version:

```js
const rootApp = $('#root');
var html = `<button class="clickMe">ON </button>`; // Declare your button
rootApp.append(html); // Append your HTML on desire element

$(document).on('click', '.clickMe', function() {
  $(this).text(function(i, text) {
    var txt = text.trim();
    return txt === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```